# How to use existing Spree API for sign in/sign up

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, spree

I have installed the Spree gem and am using its API for developing an Android app. I have scoured the guides provided by Spree but I am unable to find an API endpoint for sign up/sign in for my users.

Do I need another gem for this or is there a way to do it with the existing Spree app I have?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Everything User related is being handled with the [spree_auth_devise gem](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise).

However, the API calls are not supported out of the box. You would need to extend the `Spree::UserSessionsController` to accept the JSON calls. Same thing needs to be done in the `Spree::UserRegistrationsController`, if you want the mobile User to be able to register with the Android app.